# Selecting desired option with drop down menu using formula

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I was creating a sample List which has Category section, under which we have three different options, namely

- Hindu
- Muslim
- Christian

Now, I want to create another column which should help the user to select manually with a drop down option whenever the user selects each option above.
i.e:

When a user selects Hindu, he should receive 3 different option in drop down., like wise for Muslim and Christian, which shouldn't correlate to each other.

I'm not specifically looking for it in calculated field, what so ever possibly gives me a solution is okay for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are there more values that are category specific?

I see three options:

1. The simplest way to do this is simply creating 3 content types. Each content type is a category. You can give different columns to each content type/category so each has a different set of form options.
2. You could also try using a survey, it has some options to display and hide specific values/columns depending what a user selects, it lacks some flexibility in some ways tho
3. **Perhaps the best one**, is customize the form in Infopath. You can set rules in InfoPath that conditionally changes drop down selections based on actions the user has done within the form.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to build your own custom field. The following links might help you with the same.

- [Cascading dropdown (or) Filtered Values in Lookup Columns in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.in/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html#.UlJ61mW6bmI)
- [How to create a cascading dropdown list in sharepoint 2010](http://blog.erikvl87.nl/2010/10/how-to-create-a-cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Implement Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint List](http://jassimkhan.blogspot.in/2010/10/implement-cascading-dropdown-in.html)

Comment: A custom field for this sounds like a lot of work for something very simple

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for a Lookup field? Create a Separate List with Hindu Muslim and Christian category with their corresponding values and then call this list as a lookup column in your List. You will get easy guidance on creating lookup fields in internet.